# how to search in lookupvalue filter value?

Tags: filter, powerbi, vlookup, dax

I want to use lookup value in Power BI, I'm using the following expression:

```
Type_to_Freq = LOOKUPVALUE(PP_Freq[Estimate],PP_Freq[Type],"Private")
```

the problem is, I need to pull different values from the table depending the result of one filter in my page.

Can the third field of lookup value could be dynamic?

If one filter I choose "Private", obtain the result for this, and if I choose "Public", change the result of "Private" to "Public".

What do I need to change to use that expression?

Comment: Is Type_to_Freq a measure or a calculated column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
Measure :=
VAR Selection =
    SELECTEDVALUE ( PP_Freq[Type] )
RETURN
    IF (
        NOT ( ISBLANK ( Selection ) ),
        LOOKUPVALUE ( PP_Freq[Estimate], PP_Freq[Type], Selection ),
        "Make A Slection"
    )
```

Comment: Thanks !!
That is exactly that i wanted.

Comment: Great! Glad I could help

Comment: i have other question, maybe you can help me,

Comment: it´s possible pull the number from input box, in PBI inside Rscript (using R script Visual fuction)?,

Comment: As far as I know, power bi visuals cannot interact with R visuals i.e. no cross filtering so I am going to assume that the standard DAX library will not be applicable to R visuals. But I could be wrong